# What term is used to mean the game of American football?

Tags: meaning, words, usage

I see terms for soccer and football and they seem closely related. What is the term used to clearly indicate American football? National/American Football League football. Thank you for your time in answering this question.

Comment: Please try doing your own research before you ask questions here: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB

Comment: I researched the term using a standard dictionary, your post is very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, サッカー is almost exclusively used to refer to the one you use your foot for most of the time, and アメフト for the handegg version.

As some fun examples of usage, you might want to check [NFL Japan's site](https://nfljapan.com/guide/about) or read some of Murata Yusuke's [Eyeshield 21.](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8921)